# Query on firebase snapshots using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app using Firebase.

I'm stuck on an issue, I don't know how to get and display
data into tableview.

Here is a sample of my database:

[image: firebase db schema]

My app doesn't know the object ids.
I want to query on particular "nomStation" and particular "ville"
The search string come from another ViewController.

Now I coded this but it doesn't get the data I want :

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Stations")

    ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {

            let childshot = child as! DataSnapshot
            let id = childshot.key
            let path = "Stations/" + id

            ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "nomStation")
                .queryEqual(toValue: "AVIA Antony")
                .observe(.value, with: { snap in

                    if let dict = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        self.stationItem!.nomStation = dict["nomStation"] as! String
                        self.stationItem!.adresse = dict["adresse"] as! String
                        self.stationItem!.codePostal = dict["codePostal"] as! String
                        self.stationItem!.ville = dict["ville"] as! String
                        self.stationItem!.marque = dict["marque"] as! String
                        self.stationItem!.pays = dict["pays"] as! String
                        self.stationItem!.commentaire = dict["commentaire"] as! String
                        self.stationItem!.coordGPS = dict["coordGPS"] as! String
                    }

            })
        }
    })
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can try:-
`databaseRef.child("Stations").queryOrdered(byChild: "nomStation").queryEqual(toValue: "AVIA Antony")`

Comment: No need to first get the snapshot and run the query on that. You should directly run the query on databaseRef so that you can get the snapshot you are interested in.

Comment: Refer firebase sample app https://github.com/rheyansh/RFirebaseMessaging

Comment: I modified my code thanks to Ask recommendations.


I got that result on my workspace:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP0Fh.png

I want to access the different properties of dict object.
How can I do that please ?

The line self.stationItem!.nomStation = dict["nomStation"] as! String
throws an error because of nil value

Thank you.